# If integer variable num1 is initialized to 5, what is the value of num1 after the following code segment runs:

Tags: if-statement, break

If integer variable num1 is initialized to 5, 
what is the value of num1 after the following code segment runs:

[image]

I am a little confused on this question. Assistance would be great thanks.

Comment: It will be `7`.As num2 = 2. It will be `default` case.

Answer (score -1):

If num1 is initialized to 5, then `num1 % 3` is 2. Hence the switch statement hasn't a case that can handle the value 2, the default case will becalled. This case adds 2 to the value of num1 and stores it in num1. So in the end, num1 will be 7.

Note:

```
num1 += 2
```

is the shorthand for

```
num1 = num1 + 2
```